# header location and meta tags

Tags: php

my script index page is running random query.

**example:** click index.php and index.php redirect to topic.php?id=RANDOMID

my redirect code:

```
header("Location:topic.php?id=$randomId");
```

Right up here.

But When I wrote mysite.com on google, google give me topic's title and meta tags. I want only homepage title and meta tags.

I want home page > title,meta tags and topic page > title,meta different.

Sorry for my bad english..
Thank u..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *don't have* a homepage, you have a redirect. Since you don't have a homepage, it can't have meta data that will show up in a search index.